# service stopping sporadically

Tags: windows-services, windows-server

I have a service that will occasionally stop without reason. I have the Recovery set to restart the service, but it is not working as expected. What's the best way to determine why the service is stopping or how to determine what other factors on the server are causing the stoppage?